# Subsetting to drop rows where df$var=0 produces NA rows where var is NA

Tags: r, subset, na

I have a data.frame that I'm attempting to eliminate some observations on. I want to drop any row in which `out$SUB_AGE` is equal to `0`. However, when I try to subset my df based on that condition, it transforms any row that has `NA` for `out$SUB_AGE` into a row of `NA`s. I've provided a dput below which doesn't actually contain any rows where `out$SUB_AGE=0` but it does behave exactly the same as the full dataset which does contain zeroes does.

```
# dput the data
> temp <- dput(droplevels(out[1:12, 1:4]))
structure(list(SUB_ID = c(5998784L, 6805295L, 318926L, 1270965L, 
1635543L, 4296301L, 1001498L, 2388387L, 2190957L, 4168048L, 318926L, 
4073180L), ORG_ID = c(10861L, 17361L, 10608L, 11099L, 13135L, 
14803L, 12359L, 13151L, 13135L, 17252L, 10608L, 17317L), SUB_AGE = c(36, 
NA, NA, 40, 60, 50, 52, 61, 56, 62, NA, NA), SUB_SEX = c(NA, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2)), .Names = c("SUB_ID", "ORG_ID", 
"SUB_AGE", "SUB_SEX"), row.names = c(107L, 190L, 242L, 331L, 
361L, 447L, 455L, 591L, 663L, 664L, 731L, 732L), class = "data.frame")


# table before subsetting
     SUB_ID ORG_ID SUB_AGE SUB_SEX
107 5998784  10861      36      NA
190 6805295  17361      NA       1
242  318926  10608      NA       2
331 1270965  11099      40       1
361 1635543  13135      60       2
447 4296301  14803      50       2
455 1001498  12359      52       1
591 2388387  13151      61       2
663 2190957  13135      56       2
664 4168048  17252      62      NA
731  318926  10608      NA       2
732 4073180  17317      NA       2


# code to subset
temp <- temp[temp$SUB_AGE != 0,]


# table after subsetting
      SUB_ID ORG_ID SUB_AGE SUB_SEX
107  5998784  10861      36      NA
NA        NA     NA      NA      NA
NA.1      NA     NA      NA      NA
331  1270965  11099      40       1
361  1635543  13135      60       2
447  4296301  14803      50       2
455  1001498  12359      52       1
591  2388387  13151      61       2
663  2190957  13135      56       2
664  4168048  17252      62      NA
NA.2      NA     NA      NA      NA
NA.3      NA     NA      NA      NA
```

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing here but I racked my brain and apparently couldn't come up with the right combination of keywords to figure it out myself.

Comment: I ran it as `subset(temp, temp$SUB_AGE != 0)` and all it's doing is the same as above but dropping those NA rows.

Comment: No, I want to keep rows where `SUB_AGE` has any value not zero, including `NA`. The error is that it's creating the all-`NA` rows. Also, ran it both iwith and without `temp$` and got the same. That was a dumb typo on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the problem, try printing `temp$SUB_AGE != 0`:

```
[1] TRUE   NA   NA TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

You're using this vector to subset `temp`, but that functionality only works for TRUE/FALSE values. If you want to keep all the rows with NA values, you can add an extra condition:

```
temp[temp$SUB_AGE != 0 | is.na(temp$SUB_AGE),]
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. I think it's a bit of a clunky workaround but it works so I'm happy with it! Thanks for explaining it too.